# Flutter pub get Handshake exception

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, sslhandshakeexception

I have been working with flutter for a couple of months. Since yesterday I have had the following issue, 
which makes me unable to work.

I have to emphasize, that I'm working behind a corporate proxy.

When trying to get the packages specified in my pubspec file, I'm receiving the following error.

**HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:352))**

I have the same error using the latest
v1.12.13+hotfix.8 flutter, dart SDK 2.7
and with
v1.9.1+hotfix.6 flutter, dart SDK 2.5

Flutter doctor shows, that everything seems to be fine. My PROXY configuration is correct, but when it starts to download the packages I receive this handshake error.

Does anyone have any idea where is the problem?
Is it in my local machine, or something in the PROXY or the corporate network?
What can I do to fix the error?

**Stacktrace**

```
[        ] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera/versions/0.5.7+1.tar.gz
[        ]     | X-Pub-OS: windows
[        ]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: F610ABB6-F1FF-462D-98FC-35769BE11F92
[        ]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_cli:get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[        ]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.5.0
[ +518 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +1 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[   +1 ms]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: self signed certificate in certificate chain(handshake.cc:352))
[   +1 ms]     |
[        ]     | dart:_http                                 _HttpClient.openUrl
[        ]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36      IOClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                 _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart         RetryClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 194:43           _ThrowingClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                 _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart   ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 322:37  BoundHostedSource._download
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                 _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart            Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 41:23     GetCommand.run
[        ]     | package:args/command_runner.dart 194:27    CommandRunner.runCommand
```